# urllib2.urlopen behaving weird

Tags: python, urllib2, wsgi

I am using python 2.7.5. I am using urllib2.urlopen() to make a client request to local server. When I write this piece of code seperately on my machine..it works smoothly

```
import json
import urllib2


urls = [ "https://localhost/rest/service1", 
         "https://localhost/rest/service2" ]
for url in urls:
    url_encoded  = urllib2.quote(url, safe="-:?=/")
    token = 'f42fa4d43db94c2782feabf84fa2cc90'
    headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-Auth-Token": token }
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request( url_encoded, headers=headers )
        response = urllib2.urlopen( request )
        reply = response.read()
        data = json.loads(reply)
        print data
    except Exception as ex:
        msg = ex.msg
        print msg
```

Same piece of code invoked in my project using WSGI rest framework gives this error:

```
-> response = urllib2.urlopen( request )
(Pdb)
URLError: URLError...:579)'),)
```

Please guide me in this.. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Can you show the actual output of your code (and any stacktrace).  There's no `pdb` in your example code.

Comment: Yes I have not added any pdb in the example code as it works fine. but to get the exact failure in my project code, I was tracing it with pdb. The same method (urllib2.urlopen(request)) works fine when invoked seperately on the same machine.

Comment: Yes I have not added any pdb in the example code as it works fine. but to get the exact failure in my project code, I was tracing it with pdb. The same method (urllib2.urlopen(request)) works fine when invoked seperately on the same machine.

After debugging it more..i got to know its a SSL connection failure.